# How does a server discover an OpenId Provider's authentication's endpoint?

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid

If a person enters in their OpenId authentication provider as: `http://www.myopenid.com` ... how can I discover that the real endpoint I need to 302 redirect them to is `https://www.myopenid.com/server` ?

BTW: I only know `https://www.myopenid.com/server` is the endpoint because I've been **manually** snopping the traffic in my browser (eg. when I attempt to login in on StackOverflow via their MyOpenId icon/pic).

Any clues, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenID 2.0 Specification explains the discovery process [1]. There are three discovery methods discussed in the specification.

1. XRI Resulution
2. Yadis Protocol
3. HTML Based Discovery

The libraries you are using to implement the OpenID Relying Party should be supporting these methods, so they would calculate the OP endpoint.

[1]. http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#discovery